# How to add event listener in `setup` function?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

As of vue3, the `$on` method is no longer supported.

To add an event listener I have to write it on the element itself.

```
<transition name="fade" @after-enter="afterEnter">
    <div>foobar</div>
</transition>
```

in the above sample, the `afterEnter` function have to be exposed to the component's context, but I want it to not be exposed to the component's context.

In vue2, we can just call the `$on('after-enter', afterEnter)`. But how about in vue3 to do this?

Comment: are talking about event bus or transition hooks?

Comment: @Boussadjra Brahim Transition hooks

Comment: @yaquawa Am I right in thinking you want to add an event listener without updating the template? What did your Vue 2 code look like? (how did you bind `after-enter`?)

Answer (score 1):

You should return afterEnter listener from the setup function.

```
<script>
export default {
  setup() {
    return { afterEnter: () => console.log('after enter hook') }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you might be confused. Running this code will NOT add the event listener to `attrs` in `context`. It only does this when you set an event on an instance of a component. For example:

```
<template>
    <button>
        Toggle
    </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'MyButton',
    setup(props, { attrs }) {
      console.log(attrs); // Proxy {__vInternal: 1, onClick: ƒ}
    },
}
</script>
```

```
<my-button @click="handleClick"></my-button>
```

If you do NOT want the event to appear in `attrs` in this case, you must declared it with `emits`.

```
<template>
    <button>
        Toggle
    </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'MyButton',
    emits: ['click'],   // declare here
    setup(props, { attrs }) {
      console.log(attrs); // Proxy {__vInternal: 1}  the event listener is gone
    },
}
</script>
```

```
<my-button @click="handleClick"></my-button>
```

Alternatively, if you really want to use `$on`, you can use a external library like [mitt](https://github.com/developit/mitt) or [tiny-emitter](https://github.com/scottcorgan/tiny-emitter) to utilize the same API from Vue 2.

### Here's some resources if that doesn't answer your question:

https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/emits-option.html#overview
https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/events-api.html